# If I add a new partition into an encrypted LVM will that added space be unencrypted?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, lvm

This is my HDD layout for now:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1 - /boot/efi (512M)
/dev/sda2 - /boot     (1024M)
/dev/sda3 - / encrypted LVM (700G)
unallocated - 220G
```

Now what I want to do is move that last `220G` into the encrypted `LVM`, now the question is then will that space be encrypted **or will that be left un-encrypted ?**

If you are wondering why that 220 GB is unallocated that is because the Anaconda installer did not know or have any option to put that into the volume group. I need that for creating LVM snapshots.

What I will be doing to extend the LVM, is create a new partition out of that unallocated space then I will run a `vgextend` command like:

```
vgextend /dev/volgroup0 /dev/sda4
```

**Is this the correct way?**

Encryption Method: **luks2**

**lsblk output**

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1              8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2              8:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3              8:3    0   700G  0 part  
  └─vgfedora-root 253:0    0   700G  0 lvm   
    └─luks-5588f22e-e9fc-48f6-9b06-4c6905cd3135
```

**pvs output**

```
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  vgfedora lvm2 a--  700.00g    0
```

**vgs output**

```
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vgfedora   1   1   0 wz--n- 700.00g    0
```

Comment: What mechanism is used to encrypt the LVM? Could you post the `lsblk`,  `pvs`, `vgs` output to show the _actual_ layout?

Comment: @user1686 I have added the requested information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Encrypted LVM" can mean two different configurations: either LUKS on top of a LVM logic volume, or LVM physical volume on top of LUKS.

You have the former – and it's not actually LVM that is encrypted, it's only the logical volume's *contents* that are encrypted.

So you can safely add new physical volumes; the data will remain encrypted, because it gets encrypted before it even reaches LVM.